# How can I clone a Test Plan via the Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, test-plan

The issue is that one specific Test Plan on an Azure DevOps Server (Version 2020.1.2) needs to be cloned regularly. Right now, this replication encompasses multiple steps (renaming the plan, changing the iteration paths of the plan and underlying suites, modifying the queries of the suites, ...). All these steps are currently done manually. As this practice leaves a lot of room for human error it has now become a requirement to do the replication programmatically.

Azure DevOps offers a REST API and a .NET SDK for this exact purpose. I am using the NuGet package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` (Version 16.205.1). I used the following code to create a clone:

```cs
public async Task<TestPlan> CloneTestPlanAsync(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var vssConnection = new VssConnection("{PROJECT_COLLECTION_URI}", {VssCredentials});
    TestPlanHttpClient client = await vssConnection.GetClientAsync<TestPlanHttpClient>(cancellationToken);
    TestPlan sourceTestPlan = await client.GetTestPlanByIdAsync(
        project: _projectName,
        planId: id,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    var cloneRequestBody = new CloneTestPlanParams()
    {
        sourceTestPlan = new SourceTestPlanInfo()
        {
            id = id
        },
        destinationTestPlan = new DestinationTestPlanCloneParams()
        {
            Name = $"{sourceTestPlan.Name} Clone"
        },
        cloneOptions = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.CloneOptions()
        {
            CopyAllSuites = true,
            CopyAncestorHierarchy = true
        }
    };
    CloneTestPlanOperationInformation cloneInfo = await client.CloneTestPlanAsync(
        cloneRequestBody: cloneRequestBody,
        project: _projectName,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    return await client.GetTestPlanByIdAsync(
        project: _projectName,
        planId: cloneInfo.destinationTestPlan.Id,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Unfortunately, the result is not as expected. Only the test plan itself is cloned without the suites. Also, the method `CloneTestPlanAsync` from the imported library does not seem to work properly. It throws a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` with the message `Required property 'opId' not found in JSON. Path 'cloneOperationResponse'`. However, the clone is still created! The exception seems to occur during creation of the return value (`CloneTestPlanOperationInformation`).

Trying the same operation with the REST API reinforces my assumption:

```http
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/CloneOperation?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

The response always contains the following object:

```json
"cloneOperationResponse": {
    "state": "queued",
    "links": {
        "_self": {
            "href": "http://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/CloneOperation/0"
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I send with the request body, the response points to the clone operation "**0**", which does not exist.

I am aware that the method I used is - as of the time of writing - marked as preview and therefore I should not expect everything to work perfectly. I still want to ask: How can I clone a test plan along with its test suites using the above mentioned NuGet package?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the `suiteIds` in the `sourceTestPlan`.

Kindly take reference to the following sample body and screenshots to help understand.

```
{
    "cloneOptions": {
        "cloneRequirements": false,
        "copyAllSuites": true,
        "copyAncestorHierarchy": true
    },
    "destinationTestPlan": {
        "areaPath": "TheProjectName",
        "iteration": "TheProjectName",
        "project": "TheProjectName",
        "name": "Test 1 Cloned by API"
    },
    "sourceTestPlan": {
        "id": 5,
        "suiteIds": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the `suiteIds` worked for me. However, I still don't know what the exact purpose of `copyAllSuites` is. Regardless of the property's value, only the suites which are specified in the `suiteIds` are actually cloned. Is that part of the API just broken or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hi @Huadara, Thx for the sharing. I noticed even I added `"suiteIds": []` the new test plan was created as expected. But without this field, the new test plan was empty. It seemed when we used `copyAllSuites` as `true`, we still needed to add `suiteIds` simply leaving it as `[]`. For this, I have updated the answer. Can you test it from your side as well? You may also consider mark this asnwer as it may help others with similar concerns. Cheers!

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thank you very much!